Criteria Builder Sort a Table before Joining?
I want to join multiple tables, but I wanted the first record of the last id. So I want to join Table A and Table B, sort that by Table B's Id in DESC order then join it to Table C.
CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<String> cq = cb.createQuery(String.class);

Root<A> a= cq.from(A.class);

cq.select(a.join("B").get("C").get("c.id")).distinct(true);

So ideally I wanted to sort table B in descending order and then group by b.id, so it only returns the a single record of the high id value from B.
I tried doing:
cq.orderby(cb.desc(A.join("B").get("C").get("C.id")))
  .groupby((A.join("B").get("B.id")));

This almost worked but the sort by descending happens after the whole entire query is executed so I just end up getting the first record from table B's id.
It looked like this in SQL:
SELECT test.b_id
FROM 
  (SELECT DISTINCT A.a_id, B.b_id, c.c_id
  FROM A
  JOIN B  on a.a_id = b.b_id
  JOIN C on b.b_id = c.c_id
  ORDER BY b.b_id DESC) as test
GROUP BY test.a_id
ORDER by test.b_id DESC;

